# rbs(remote blob storage) wont disable

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql, rbs, upgrade-sharepoint

target is to upgrade sharepoint 2013 to 2016.
i have backed up the contentDB and restore it 
it will mount in new web app in 2016 farm but there s some problem:
first. it kinda seem like it mounted uncomplete because when i view my site collections in central admin at left i can see my site collection but at right there s no box of information.
second. after mount i run upgrade-spcontentdatabase command but i got error about RBS.(it seems farm 2013 database was RBS enabled but in new database i failed to enable rbs) i tried to disable rbs from content database by run commands in this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/disable-rbs-on-a-content-database
but nothing happend
how can i disable RBS ?

Comment: I haven't faced your scenario but if you had RBS enabled on the 2013 you need to disable it there and then do the backup of the DB and mount it in 2016 otherwise you are left without the BLOBS in you database.

Comment: if want to disable it in 2013 database can i disable it only for this database or i have to disable it in sql server

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a new contentDB in 2013, without RBS enabled on the DB.  Then use powershell to move the site in question to the new database, Move-SPsite command.  Then migrate the new clean DB to SP2016.

I also found this article, but I don't think that the BLOBS are actually moved from the file system back to the content DB, so proceed with caution. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/disable-rbs-on-a-content-database

Comment: that s actually a good idea but i cant move the site collection . is there any way to copy the site collection database to a new database?

Comment: i found copy-spsite i will try it later when i have access to server. but i tried backup-spsite before and because of some kind of database corruption at the end an error occured...i hope copy-spsite will work

Comment: Why can't you use the Move-SPsite command?  Is the DB huge or something?

Comment: No because the site collection is main company s portal and it's too risky